# duplicate key value violates unique constraint in typorm postgress

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, nestjs, typeorm

I am having an issue with typeorm + postgres on my production server, it keep throwing this error in the console but the app is still running (Not breasking)

Nest] 41  - 11/03/2022, 9:44:20 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UQ_167efd0746b6a9808b96f2e0d66"
QueryFailedError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UQ_167efd0746b6a9808b96f2e0d66"
at QueryFailedError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (/app/src/error/TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
at new QueryFailedError (/app/src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
at PostgresQueryRunner. (/app/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:247:19)
at step (/app/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:144:27)
at Object.throw (/app/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:125:57)
at rejected (/app/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:116:69)
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Answer (score 1):

It means your are inserting some data that already exist in the database.
If you wanna insert same data into database,
Define your columns in your entity like this:

```
@Column({ unique: false })
firstName: string;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. this is how i define my columns

 ` @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false })`

do i still need to add the unique: false explicitly??

actually i have about 30K + Data in the database

Comment: yes, if you wanna add same data that already exist in the database you should add this. otherwise it keep throwing duplicate key value error. (don't forget to accept and upvote my answer :-) )

Comment: Thank you for the responses.. after adding the unique: false explicitly to all my columns is still throwing the same error in the server logs..

what next should i do??

Comment: Do u run your migration again?.. if you don't use migration you should enable synchronize in your database config like this: `synchronize : true`. this will update your changes into database. you can see some examples here:  [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database)